# JavaFX 2.x : switch from linear to log Y axis

Tags: charts, javafx-2

I have a XY Chart serie plotted as linear using Y axis as NumberAxis.

With a flag on a CheckBox I would like to switch dynamically from (Y only) NumberAxis to LogarithmicAxis.

How to perform this? Is there a repaint method or something similar? Or should I delete the whole serie and replot again?

PS I am not asking how to plot data as logarithm, this is a solved issue.

Comment: I believe you should replot again. If you met performance issues you can have two charts and make them visible by turns